# ¿Por qué un SELECT devuelve todos los registros y no solamente los que cumplen una condición?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con varios registros y quiero hacer un conteo de los mismos, pero sólo de aquellos que cumplen una condición.

Aquí mi código:

```
<?php

include 'cn.php';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM fallas WHERE    estatus='SOLUCIONADO'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query); 
$total= mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $total;
?>
```

Lo que pretendo es contar sólo los registros que en el campo ESTATUS contenga la palabra SOLUCIONADO. Según yo, con ese código lograría eso, pero me muestra el total de registros y no los que cumplen con el condicional.

¿Podrían ayudarme y decirme en donde estoy mal?

Comment: Defines `$sql = "` pero luego usas `$query` al llamar a `mysqli_query()`. ¿Es realmente así en tu código o es un error de transcripción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a usar `SELECT COUNT(*)`, entonces la base de datos es la que está haciendo el cálculo y siempre te va a devolver **un (1)** solo registro (con el numero de resultados), así que en ese caso no tienes que usar `mysqli_num_rows($resultado)`, si no `mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)`. 
Otra cosa, en tu código estás usando una variable "`$sql`" y después estás usando otra no definida "`$query`"

Debe quedar algo asi:

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM fallas WHERE estatus='SOLUCIONADO'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$total = $fila['total'];
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $total;
```

Otra forma que debe dar el mismo resultado es trayendo las filas que cumplen la condición del query y luego contándolas ahora con PHP, con `mysqli_num_rows`, algo más parecido a lo que estabas haciendo. 
Este caso no es el más eficiente si solo necesitas el número de registros ya que COUNT(*) lo hace. Pero si el resultado si lo vas a utilizar posteriormente, entonces si es buena opción, incluso te ahorras una consulta a la base de datos.

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$sql = "SELECT idtabla, column1, column2... FROM fallas WHERE estatus='SOLUCIONADO'"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
$total= mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
echo 'Número de total de registros: ' . $total;
```

Comment: Hola que tal, probé de la segunda forma que me hiciste saber y funciona, te agradezco mucho de antemano.

Comment: Si es **sólo para saber cuántos registros existen** la 2ª forma que propones no tiene ningún sentido y sería hasta absurdo hacer eso sólo para contar los registros, más aún sabiendo que `COUNT(*)` está optimizado a nivel de la base de datos. La 2ª forma sólo (¿podría?)  ser útil si aparte de saber cuántas filas hay interesan además los datos de todas esas filas, y aún en ese supuesto, existe la propiedad  `affected_rows` para saber en el caso 2 la cantidad de filas que arrojó esa consulta.

Comment: Tienes razón @A.Cedano Puse el segundo caso solo porque era más parecido a lo que trataba de hacer. Sin embargo ese caso sería eficiente solo si el resultado de la consulta va a ser usado posteriormente en otras operaciones. Modifiqué la respuesta con esa advertencia.